# how to submit multiple row in mysql using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

How can I submit multiple rows in MySQL using PHP and javascript?

This page submits only a single row of data to mysql and I want to submit multiple rows.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/3/)

This is the PHP for that page:

```
<form  action="multi.php" method="post">
<body ng:app>
  <h2>Shopping Card Example</h2>
<div ng:controller="CartForm">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items">
            <td><input type="text" ng:model="item.description" name="description" value="" class="input-small"></td>           
            <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.qty" name="qty" value="" ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
            <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.cost" name="cost" value=""  ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
            <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency}}</td>
            <td>
                [<a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>]
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href ng:click="addItem()" class="btn btn-small">add item</a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>{{total() | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
    <div align="center">
      <input name="submit"  type="submit"  class="btn btn-small" value="submit"/>
       &nbsp;
       <input name="Reset"  type="reset" class="btn btn-small"  value="Reset"/>
       </div>


</form>

<?php

 function renderForm($description, $qty, $cost, $error)
 {
 ?>


 <?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 



 <?php 
 }


 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // get form data, making sure it is valid

 $description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));
 $qty = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['qty']));
 $cost = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cost']));

 // check to make sure both fields are entered
 if ($qty == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($description, $qty,$cost, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
  mysql_query("INSERT stock SET description='$description', qty='$qty', cost='$cost'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page

 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','','','','','','');
 }

         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a name with empty brackets in your input tags, something like:

```
<td><input type="text" name="description[]" ...></td>           
<td><input type="number" name="qty[]" ...></td>
<td><input type="number" name="cost[]" ...></td>
```

Then, in php, you'd get 3 **arrays**, like this:

```
$descriptions = $_POST['description'];
$qtys = $_POST['qty'];
$costs = $_POST['cost'];
```

then you can traverse each array as any other php array

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: i change it but now this error is showing Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in E:\xampp\htdocs\j\multi.php on line 139

Comment: and 139 line this   $descriptions = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));
 $qtys = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['qty']));
 $costs = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cost']));

Comment: You have to traverse the array first, then apply htmlspecialchars and your logic per each array item.

Comment: i remove htmlspcilchrs and using this $descriptions = $_POST['description'];
$qtys = $_POST['qty'];
$costs = $_POST['cost'];  but now no data submit in mysql table

Comment: Are you traversing these arrays?

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT stock SET description='$description', qty='$qty', cost='$cost'") can i change this code also ??? like descriptions qtys costs

Comment: yes, you have to TRAVERSE the array first, and then apply your old logic on each element in the array, something like:
    `for($i=0; $i< count($qtys) $i++){
      $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($qtys[$i]);
      $cost = mysql_real_escape_string($costs[$i]);
      //INSERT INTO... etc
    }`

Comment: Also, your INSERT syntax is wrong. It's INSERT INTO, not INSERT..SET